# Set timezone in Bootstrap file

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

In my application having one default timezone. And every users have their own timezone. I want to set the user timezone which is stored in the database.

How to set the timezone according to users in Bootstrap file.

Thanks in advance...

```
class Crm_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {

    protected function _initTimezone()
    {

        $userObj = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
        require_once('Zend/Session.php');
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('logincred');
        $userdetails = $userObj->userdetails($session->user);
        date_default_timezone_set($userdetails[0][id]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an initTimezone() bootstrap method, retrieve the timezone of the user/session from the database and set the timezone, if user is not logged in, set default timezone.

Comment: Please see my question i have added my code. If this is wrong please provide me correct code. Thanks for your help...

Comment: Does it work? There are a few problems/issues with this code, many things are solved in a suboptimal way. First thing: Why are you not using the autoloader?

Comment: Also tried with autoloader. When trying to use ` $userObj = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
        require_once('Zend/Session.php');
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('logincred');
` I am getting only blank white screen.

Answer (score 0):

You'd also need to do this in the login method for users as well as the bootstrap, otherwise the initial pageview after they've logged in successfully would have an incorrect timezone.

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    // .. login code ..
    // .. login successful ..
    date_default_timezone_set($user->timezone);
}
```

Comment: Please see my question i have added my code. If this is wrong please provide me correct code. Thanks for your help...

Comment: I would assume that `$userdetails[0][id]` is incorrect, that would surely get you the user id? You need to get the timezone column, and also enclose column names in quotes, you're not using a constant. Example: `$userdetails[0]['timezone']`

Comment: Okay that's a typo mistake. But I tried with $userdetails[0]['timezone'].

Comment: Well then you need to debug, use `print_r($userdetails);` and see what's available to you, it may be that it's just `$userdetails['timezone']`. I'm not really a Zend dev so I can't be sure how to reply, but stil...

Answer (score 0):

Iam using doctrine2+Symbony 
check user name row in data base.

```
$userRepo = $em->getRepository('modules\user\models\Users')->find($userId);
```

fetch time zone in your db and  place the value in function

```
$timezone = $userRepo->timezone;
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
```

code is

```
 class Crm_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {

    public function init()
    {

        $em = $this->getEntityManager('user');
    @$userId = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->id;
    $userManager = new UsersManager();
    if ($userId) {

        $userRepo = $em->getRepository('modules\user\models\Users')->find($userId);
        date_default_timezone_set($userRepo->timezone);

    }
    }
}
```

you create time zone field in db table